# jquery ajax call can be simply run through plain html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to UI dev. Right now, I am trying to use jQuery ajax call to fetch data from some existing api. Below is my code in a plain html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    'url': 'http://baseURL/endpoint/',
                    'type': 'GET',
                    'content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'headers': {
                        'Authorization': 'Token 1234567890'
                    },
                    'success': function () {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    'error': function () {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

However, when I try to load this page on my local (copy url http://localhost:63342/dirctorypath/html/index.html to IE and hit enter). It doesn't show alert at all. I start to wonder if I can simply load page like this to make the embedded ajax call run. Or I have to deploy it using some web server. Please help.

Comment: what do you see in the console?

Comment: which console? I use F12 and I can see the above code in the Debugger tab. Also, it seems there is no API request coming in to my api server according to the log. This probably means the api request not even sent out.

Comment: If you press Esc in the Developer tools (the window from pressing F12) it will open up a console where error and log commands will print to, and where you can execute JavaScript on the fly. EDIT: this is assuming you're using Chrome. If not the Esc shortcut may not work, but there should still be a console tab in the same developer tools window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your JS tags mixed up, the following should give you a better start. It moves the actual JS code into it's own 'script' tags.

Furthermore, you should move this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

into the head of your HTML.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                    'url': 'http://baseURL/endpoint/',
                    'type': 'GET',
                    'content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'headers': {
                        'Authorization': 'Token 1234567890'
                    },
                    'success': function () {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    'error': function () {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I would explicitly add the reasons for doing this - that you cannot mix the src attribute with actual JavaScript content in the same script tag, and that moving the jQuery script tag into the head will ensure it's loaded before the rest of the page.  Knowing why it doesn't work rather than just how to fix it can help avoid similar issues in the future.